# Mapping values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, mapping, key-value

How do I go from a 2D numpy array where I only have three distinct values: -1, 0, and 1 and map them to the colors `red` (255,0,0), `green` (0,255,0), and `blue` (255,0,0)? The array is quite large, but to give you an idea of what I am looking for, imagine I have the input

```
array([[ 1,  0, -1],
       [-1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  1]])
```

I want the output:

```
array([[(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)],
       [(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)],
       [(0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]])
```

I could for-loop and have conditions but I was wondering if there is a one or two liner using a lambda function that could accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider a structured array, as it allows tuples without the datatype being `object`.

```
import numpy as np

replacements = {-1: (255, 0, 0), 0: (0, 255, 0), 1: (0, 0, 255)}

arr = np.array([[ 1,  0, -1],
                [-1,  1,  1],
                [ 0,  0,  1]])

new = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=np.dtype([('r', np.int32), ('g', np.int32), ('b', np.int32)]))

for n, tup in replacements.items():
    new[arr == n] = tup

print(new)
```

Output:

```
[[(  0,   0, 255) (  0, 255,   0) (255,   0,   0)]
 [(255,   0,   0) (  0,   0, 255) (  0,   0, 255)]
 [(  0, 255,   0) (  0, 255,   0) (  0,   0, 255)]]
```

---

Another option is using an 3D array, where the last dimension is `3`. The first "layer" would be red, the second "layer" would be green, and the third "layer" blue. This option is compatible with `plt.imshow()`.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 1,  0, -1],
                [-1,  1,  1],
                [ 0,  0,  1]])

new = np.zeros((*arr.shape, 3))

for i in range(-1, 2):
    new[i + 1, arr == i] = 255
```

Output:

```
array([[[  0.,   0., 255.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0., 255.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [255., 255.,   0.]],

       [[255.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0., 255., 255.],
        [  0.,   0., 255.]]])
```

Comment: This is a nice idea! The only thing is the output `new` is in the format dtype=[('r', '<i4'), ('g', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')]. I should have mentioned this, but my goal is to call Maplotlib's imshow so when I do `plt.imshow(new)` I get the error `Image data cannot be converted to float`. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Use `img.view((np.uint32, 3))` to get in in a form matplotlib understands

Comment: @JaneSully In addition to Eric's option, I added another possibility to my answer.